# Adding repository collaborator as deployment reviewer

Tags: github, github-actions

I am playing around with GitHub environments, specifically checking out on the actions approval feature.

I have created the related infrastructure in order to support this and I have also added a colleague as a collaborator to the project. I am trying to add them as a deployment reviewer as mentioned in this document, however the selection box in the related view does not list their name. As mentioned above, their access is set to collaborator and the doc states the following:

> The reviewers must have at least read access to the repository.

So I do not think that this is a permission issue. Can anyone help with this?

Related documentation:

1. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments#about-required-reviews-in-workflows
2. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It seems that the input on the page needs the full name of a team member in order to assign them as reviewers. Simply typing part of it does not work and gives the impression that it cannot find eligible reviewers.